# Show div inside contenteditable basing on text

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I need to add div inside contenteditable div basing on contenteditable div text. Example case:

```
const ceDiv = document.getElementById('foo')

//and when text in ceDiv ends with {{ i need to show another div in current caret position
```

something like Facebook did with mentioning friends

what i did now is replacing {{var}} with div:

```
export function findAndReplaceBrackets(string: string): string {
    const bracketReg = /\{{2}(.*?)\}{2}/ig
    const brackets = string.match(bracketReg)
    if (!brackets) return string
    string = string.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '') // reset variables in string
    brackets.forEach(variable => {
        string = string.replace(variable, `<span style="
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: blue;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 13px;
            padding: 1px;
            margin: 0 2px;
            border-radius: 4px
        ">${variable}</span>`)
    })

    return string
}
```

but this don't fix my problem at all

Comment: can you please show what is the input and expected output

Comment: You mean to show `#ceDiv` behavior i am getting now?